# Grab data from Dynamic Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Attempting to grab data from Dynamic Element before submission of form to calculate duration of time.

As shown in the picture, I have [image]
Day 1 works perfectly, However Day 2 does not calculate the duration of hours. Not sure why that is. Also Unable to edit day 1 once I click to add another day but interested in how to go about fixing the first issue.

```js
  var template;
  var numOfSegments = 1;

  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
   template = document.querySelector("#wrapper").innerHTML;
   document.querySelector("#more_fields").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // tell the browser to not send the form
    document.getElementById('wrapper').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', template); // add next segment
    numOfSegments = document.querySelectorAll("div.segment").length;
    document.querySelector("div.segment:last-of-type > label").innerHTML = "Day " + (numOfSegments) + ":"; //Updates Segment #
   });
  })


  function deleteMe() {
   if (numOfSegments > 1) {
    var btn = document.querySelector("#wrapper > div.segment:last-of-type");
    btn.remove();
    event.preventDefault();
   }
  }

  function addNumSeg() {
   var elem = document.getElementById("segments_num");
   elem.value = ++numOfSegments;
  }

  function subtractNumSeg() {
   var elem = document.getElementById("segments_num");
   if (numOfSegments > 1) {
    elem.value = --numOfSegments;
   }
  }
```

```html
  <div id='segments_num' value=1 >
  <form id="seg" oninput="z.value=parseInt(segout.value)-parseInt(segin.value)">
  <div id="room_fileds">
   <div class="content" id="wrapper">
    <div class="segment">
     <label id="seg[]" style="margin:0 0 10px 60px;display: inline;">Day 1:</label>
     <div class="form-group" style="display: inline;">
      <label id=seg-in[] style="margin:0 0 10px 35px;display: inline;">IN:</label>
      <input class="form-control seg_in" id="segin" type="text" style="margin:0 0 10px 5px;Width:15%;display: inline;">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group" style="display: inline;">
      <label id=seg-out[] style="margin:0 0 10px 35px;display: inline;">OUT:</label>
      <input class="form-control seg_out" id="segout" type="text" style="margin:0 0 10px 5px;Width:15%;display: inline;">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group" style="display: inline;">
      <label id="seg-dur[]" style="margin:0 0 10px 35px;display: inline;">Duration:</label>
      <output class="form-control seg_out" form="seg" name="z" for="segin segout" style="margin:0 0 10px 5px;Width:15%;display:inline"; readonly></output>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div style="text-align:right;">
   <div style="display:inline;text-align: right;">
    <button onclick="deleteMe(); subtractNumSeg();" type="button" style="height: 25px;width:14px;" id="less_fields">-</button>
   </div>

   <div style="display:inline;text-align: right;">
    <button onclick="addNumSeg();" type="button" style="height: 25px;width:14px;" id="more_fields">+</button>
   </div>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="formSubmit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: You're copying html which has `id`s, and those need to be unique across the entire page

Comment: Not certain by what you mean by this, am I not able to grab oninput data from each "wrapper" in my case.